# An error occured while executing doInBackground() while doing facebook like

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have this do fb like code:

```
private void fbLike_optionA() {

    Bundle params1 = new Bundle();
    params1.putString("object", "http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791");
    /* make the API call */
    new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/og.likes", params1,
            HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    /* handle the result */

                    String a = "1";
                }
            }).executeAsync();
}
```

is the error because of the fake(?) url ?

`"http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791"`

I tun and get this error:

```
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:575)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask.executeOnSettingsExecutor(RequestAsyncTask.java:186)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAsync(Request.java:1838)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAsync(Request.java:1813)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAsync(Request.java:1790)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.facebook.Request.executeAsync(Request.java:1562)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.zoomer.general.ImageAdapter.fbLike_optionA(ImageAdapter.java:508)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.zoomer.general.ImageAdapter.access$0(ImageAdapter.java:479)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.zoomer.general.ImageAdapter$LikeFbPostAsyncTask.doInBackground(ImageAdapter.java:735)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.zoomer.general.ImageAdapter$LikeFbPostAsyncTask.doInBackground(ImageAdapter.java:1)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-09 12:36:58.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     ... 4 more
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030): Activity com.zoomer.offers.OffersListActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{427e3368 V.E..... R....... 0,0-640,1230} that was originally added here
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.zoomer.offers.OffersListActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{427e3368 V.E..... R....... 0,0-640,1230} that was originally added here
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:454)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at com.zoomer.general.ImageAdapter$4.onClick(ImageAdapter.java:311)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
06-09 12:36:59.106: E/WindowManager(1030):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to use this library ([details here](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/06/facebook-like-button-for-android.html)):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:facebook-like-button:0.1.8'
}
```

This library implements 'like' action using `WebView` and `<iframe>`-based [facebook plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button).

Look at the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown by this method of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params) {
    if (mStatus != Status.PENDING) {
        switch (mStatus) {
            case RUNNING:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot execute task:"
                        + " the task is already running.");
            case FINISHED:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot execute task:"
                        + " the task has already been executed "
                        + "(a task can be executed only once)");
        }
    }

    mStatus = Status.RUNNING;

    onPreExecute();

    mWorker.mParams = params;
    exec.execute(mFuture);

    return this;
}
```

So it means that somewhere you try to execute already running task.

Comment: I cannot see where. how can I bypass this?

Comment: You need to figure out where do you use execute `AsyncTask`.

Comment: what do you mean? I know ui thread can have few async tasks in his handler's queue no? I should look for async-task for the same url?   
do i need to change the fake url "samples.ogp.me/226075010839791"; ?